# iterate over an array and delete elements conditionally

Tags: ruby, exception

I want to iterate over an array of URLs, and remove elements from it if there is a timeout with the HTTP request for the given URL. It has been implemented in the following way:

```
@urls.delete_if do |url|
  begin
    doc = perform_request(some_params)
    break
  rescue TimeoutError
    Rails.logger.warn("URL #{url} times out, will be removed from list")
    true
  end
end
```

Anyone for a cleaner solution?

Comment: codereview.stackexchange.com is probably a better place for this question.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot more things that can go wrong than timeout, and it's better to ask the affirmative than the negative. That is, does the site respond in the way I want, rather than the does the site not respond in the way I want.

Furthermore, I would encourage practicing immutability, that is, not changing your data in place, but rather creating new versions from the old. My version would look like:

```
@urls = %w[www.google.com www.example.com]
valid_urls = @urls.select{ |url| up?(url)} #=> [www.google.com]

def up?(url)
  Net::HTTP.new(url).head('/').kind_of? Net::HTTPOK
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems reasonable, except the `break` in the cycle. I also like the cleanness of the solution.

Comment: Exactly, hate the break in there that's why posted it - maybe someone has a better idea how to implement this cleaner.

Comment: @EmilPetkov Why do you need the break?

Comment: If the URL works, should not remove it and should continue with processing out of the block. Without break will continue doing requests for all URLs. Btw. "true" can be removed :)

Comment: @EmilPetkov Maybe I don't get your idea then: you need to see if any of the urls work and start using the first one working, is it?

Comment: Yes, when the first works it should be used and that's it. On the other hand, if there is a timeout, the URL should be removed from the list. If a URL is removed from the list, we should continue with the next one and so on.